# Use VBA to add recipients from address book outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I have created a userform to make new meetings but i can't seem to find a way to get recipients from my address book.

Answer (score 0):

Use Aplication.Session.GetSelectNamesDialog - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/namespace-getselectnamesdialog-method-outlook?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396